# CentOS, dual route, nat

Tags: iptables

The linux server eth0 set the default route(gateway).
And the clients connected to eth2 should be able to access the internet(eth1) by nat.

Interfaces:

eth0 : LAN (default route) / IP:10.0.0.5, Gateway:10.0.0.1

eth1 : WAN / IP:10.1.0.10, Gateway:10.1.0.1

eth2 : LAN (nat via WAN) / IP : 192.168.0.1

Image:

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem requires 2 (related) things -

1. 2 routing tables
2. Policy based routing to direct traffic out the appropriate interface.

You havn't advised what distro you use, so its difficult to provide specific information of the "standard" way your distro does this, but you can, of-course, use a script like one from /etc/rc.local to bodge it, or use the info below as a starting point.

Step 1:  Set up 2 routing tables.

1. create a custom table with a unique ID with a command like "echo 200 customtable >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables"
2. Add rules for that table - unfortunately you can't use the "route" command, you need to use the "ip route command instead.  A typical rule would be "ip route add default via X.X.X.X dev ethX table customtable".  You do, of-course, need to populate this will all the relevant routes for that table.
3. Add rules to route traffic through that table.  This can be done by marking packets in iptables for some really flexible solutions, or something like "ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/8 lookup customtable.

A quick google found [this link](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/) which is probably a good guide to what you are trying to do.

Of-course, you can still use NAT and iptables to readdress the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand it, you just need to configure your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth* their respective IP addresses.
Add a gateway address to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1.
Turn your box into a router (set/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/forwarding and /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth2/forwarding to 1 using /etc/sysctl.conf)
Add your iptables nat rule (replace with appropriate values):
iptables -t nat -s $SERVER-IP-NETWORK -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE

you should be done... if I understood your network schema b(which is somewhat... unusual I have to say)

Comment: Thank you for answer. $SERVER-IP-NETWORK is what ip? eth2? eth1?

Comment: Unfortunately this is unlikely to work.  In order to do this you need to set up 2 routing tables else traffic leaving the linux server won't be routed appropriately.

Comment: indeed, I misunderstood your requirements and though eth1 was connected to your servers network, for which you didn't want external access. what you really want to achieve require toying with iproute2, routing rule and routing tables as @davidgo explained